# Extjs Grid - How to get record of first row but don't change selection

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I want to get value record of first row but don't change selection. I try

```
alert(grid.store.first().get('name'));
```

but not working. How can i do that thanks. I using extjs 4.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grid.store.getAt(0).data.name
```

Here name is the column i.e dataindex of the column, of which you need data.